# How to copy and transpose headers to another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy and transpose the headers from my source worksheet into my target sheet to use as mappings.

My code copies the row below the one I want (Row 1).

```
Sub Create_Mappings()
Dim source_sht As Worksheet
Dim target_sht As Worksheet

Dim src_raw_rng As Range 'Ranges for headings from raw_data
Dim trg_raw_rng As Range

Dim src_map_rng As Range 'Ranges for mapping headings
Dim trg_map_rng As Range

Dim last_row As Long
Dim last_column As Long

Set source_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(6)
Set target_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)

'Determine last row of data in Mappings sheet and last column in first row of Raw_Data
last_row = target_sht.Cells(target_sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
last_column = source_sht.Cells(source_sht.Range("A1"), source_sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Clear mappings

Set src_raw_rng = source_sht.Range(source_sht.Cells(1, 1), source_sht.Cells(1, last_column))

Set trg_raw_rng = target_sht.Range(Range("InpVarStart"), target_sht.Cells(last_row + 1, 3))
   
trg_raw_rng.Clear

src_raw_rng.Copy
trg_raw_rng.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Please note the comments starting with `'*`

```
Sub Create_Mappings()
  Dim source_sht As Worksheet
  Dim target_sht As Worksheet
  
  Dim src_raw_rng As Range 'Ranges for headings from raw_data
  Dim trg_raw_rng As Range
  
  Dim src_map_rng As Range 'Ranges for mapping headings
  Dim trg_map_rng As Range
  
  Dim last_row As Long
  Dim last_column As Long
  
  Set source_sht = Sheet6 ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(6)
  Set target_sht = Sheet4 ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
  
  'Determine last row of data in Mappings sheet and last column in first row of Raw_Data
  last_row = target_sht.Cells(target_sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
  
  '* changed source_sht.Range("A1") to 1
  '* you can use source_sht.Range("A1").Row, but 1 is better since you are hard-coding "A1"
  last_column = source_sht.Cells(1, source_sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  
  'Clear mappings
  
  Set src_raw_rng = source_sht.Range(source_sht.Cells(1, 1), source_sht.Cells(1, last_column))
  
  Set trg_raw_rng = target_sht.Range(Range("InpVarStart"), target_sht.Cells(last_row + 1, 3))
     
  trg_raw_rng.Clear
  
  src_raw_rng.Copy
  '* Use first cell of target range
  trg_raw_rng.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
  trg_raw_rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it really helped! I also found out that referencing my Worksheets like that referred to them in the order they are in the spreadsheet, rather than the Sheet6 I wanted to use, which caused part of the problem. Using ThisWorkbook.Sheet6 always gives an error though.

Comment: You're welcome. The main source of your error was that you did not use `.Row`, which meant that the row number was determined as the value of `Range("A1")`, which I gues was 2. And yes, referring to sheets with numbers is a bad idea. Using `ThisWorkbook.Sheet6` will generate an error, you can simply use `Sheet6` or any other code name you give to your sheet (as in the edited code).